# Marshal single field into two tags in golang

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

Trying to understand a way to create custom marshaller for xml structured as:

```xml
<Appointment>
<Date>2004-12-22</Date>
<Time>14:00</Time>
</Appointment>
```

I'm thinking of something like:

```go
type Appointment struct {
    DateTime time.Time `xml:"???"`
}
```

Question is, what would i put instead of ??? to have a single field be saved into two different xml tags?

Comment: You probably need to create your own marshaler to implement `xml.Marshaler` which will take care of splitting the `DateTime` field to `date` and `time` before marshaling to XML.

Answer (score 3):

Complex marshaling/unmarshaling behavior generally requires satisfying a Marshal/Unmarshal interface (this is of true of XML, JSON, and similarly setup types in go).

You'd need to satisfy the `xml.Marshaler` interface with a `MarshalXML()` function, something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Appointment struct {
    DateTime time.Time
}

type appointmentExport struct {
    XMLName struct{} `xml:"appointment"`
    Date    string   `xml:"date"`
    Time    string   `xml:"time"`
}

func (a *Appointment) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    n := &appointmentExport{
        Date: a.DateTime.Format("2006-01-02"),
        Time: a.DateTime.Format("15:04"),
    }
    return e.Encode(n)
}

func main() {
    a := &Appointment{time.Now()}
    output, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(a, "", "    ")
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}

// prints:
// <appointment>
//     <date>2016-04-15</date>
//     <time>17:43</time>
// </appointment>
```

Comment: Yes, this is somethingi have done. Not that it would not be a good solution, but i thought there might be some simplier solution

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess, you can't. You should implement the `xml.Marshaler` interface with your `Appointment` type…